# Redirect when Postback/Callback is send

Tags: php, html, callback, postback

is it possible to redirect a visitor on my php page as soon as I received a Postback/Callback? If yes can someone provide me some pointers where to start. Searched in Google for it but found nothing...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of your PHP page, if you include the following:

```
if( strtolower( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) == "post" ) {
    header( "Location: /your-target-page.htm" ); 
}
```

If you wanted to do a 301 redirect instead of the default 302, you could do:

```
header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); 
header( "Location: /your-target-page.htm" );
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as no other text has been sent in the response yet, all you have to do is send the redirect header, like so:

```
header( 'Location: http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.html' ) ;
```

Google for `php redirect` and you should be able to get some hits.

Also, note that a "postback" or "callback" is *just* like any other web request.